# Problem encountered while setting cometdReplayExtension

Tags: platform-event, cometd

Good morning my friends,
I'm having a problem trying to set up the dp cometd extension so that a ligthining component can process published events before its subscription. Below is my component, controller, and helper. Please let me know where I'm going wrong!

component:

```
<aura:component controller="NotificationController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

  <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.cometd, $Resource.cometdReplayExtension, $Resource.jquery, $Resource.jquery_cometd)}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.onCometdLoaded}"/>
  <aura:attribute name="sessionId" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="cometd" type="Object"/>
  <aura:attribute name="cometdSubscriptions" type="Object[]"/>

  <aura:attribute name="notifications" type="Object[]"/>
  <aura:attribute name="isMuted" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>
  <aura:registerEvent name="toastEvent" type="force:showToast"/>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="slds-p-around--x-small slds-border--bottom slds-theme--shade">
      <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread slds-grid--vertical-align-center">
        <div>
          <span class="slds-badge">{!v.notifications.length}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <lightning:buttonIcon onclick="{!c.onClear}" iconName="utility:delete" title="Clear notifications"
            alternativeText="Clear notifications" variant="border-filled"/>
          <lightning:buttonIcon onclick="{!c.onToggleMute}"
            iconName="{!v.isMuted ? 'utility:volume_off' : 'utility:volume_high'}"
            title="{!v.isMuted ? 'Unmute notifications' : 'Mute notifications'}"
            alternativeText="Toggle mute" variant="border-filled"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Notification list -->
    <div class="slds-container--fluid slds-scrollable--y content">
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.notifications}" var="notification">
        <div class="slds-p-around--small slds-border--top">
          <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <p>{!notification.message}</p>
            <p class="slds-text-color--weak slds-p-left--x-small">{!notification.time}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aura:iteration>
    </div>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
  onCometdLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
  if (component.get('v.sessionId') != null)
    helper.connectCometd(component);
},
  onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
  component.set('v.cometdSubscriptions', []);
  component.set('v.notifications', []);
  var action = component.get('c.getSessionId');
  action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    if (component.isValid() && response.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
        component.set('v.sessionId', response.getReturnValue());
    }
    else
      console.error(response);
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
  helper.displayToast(component, 'success', 'Ready to receive notifications.');
},
  onClear : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.notifications', []);
    },
  onToggleMute : function(component, event, helper) {
    var isMuted = component.get('v.isMuted');
    component.set('v.isMuted', !isMuted);
    helper.displayToast(component, 'success', 'Notifications '+ ((!isMuted) ? 'muted' : 'unmuted') +'.');
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
  connectCometd : function(component) {
    console.log('------connectCometd-----');
    var helper = this;
    var REPLAY_FROM = 'replay'
    var cometd = $.cometd;
    var compCometd = component.get('v.cometd');

    if (cometd.getExtension(REPLAY_FROM) != null) {                    
      cometd.unregisterExtension(REPLAY_FROM, replayExtension);                              
    }
    console.log('cometd.getExtension(REPLAY_FROM)');

    var replayExtension = new cometdReplayExtension();
    replayExtension.setChannel('/event/Notification__e');
    replayExtension.setReplay(-2);
    cometd.registerExtension(REPLAY_FROM, replayExtension); 

    if(compCometd != null)
            this.disconnectCometd(component);

    // Configure CometD
    var cometdUrl = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/cometd/40.0/';
    cometd.configure({
      url: cometdUrl,
      requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth '+ component.get('v.sessionId')},
      appendMessageTypeToURL : false
    });
    cometd.websocketEnabled = false;
    // Establish CometD connection
    console.log('Connecting to CometD: '+ cometdUrl);
    cometd.handshake(function(handshakeReply) {
      if (handshakeReply.successful) {
        console.log('Connected to CometD.');
        // Subscribe to platform event
        var newSubscription = cometd.subscribe('/event/Notification__e',
          function(platformEvent) {
            console.log('Platform event received: '+ JSON.stringify(platformEvent));
            helper.onReceiveNotification(component, platformEvent);
          }
        );
        // Save subscription for later
        var subscriptions = component.get('v.cometdSubscriptions');
        subscriptions.push(newSubscription);
        component.set('v.cometdSubscriptions', subscriptions);
        component.set('v.cometd', cometd);
      }
      else
        console.error('Failed to connected to CometD.');
    });
      },
  disconnectCometd : function(component) {
      console.log('------disconnectCometd-----');
    var cometd = component.get('v.cometd');
    // Unsuscribe all CometD subscriptions
    cometd.batch(function() {
      var subscriptions = component.get('v.cometdSubscriptions');
      subscriptions.forEach(function (subscription) {
        cometd.unsubscribe(subscription);
      });
    });
    component.set('v.cometdSubscriptions', []);
    // Disconnect CometD
    cometd.disconnect();
    component.set('v.cometd', cometd);
    console.log('CometD disconnected.');
  },
  onReceiveNotification : function(component, platformEvent) {
      console.log('------onReceiveNotification-----');
    var helper = this;
    // Extract notification from platform event
    var newNotification = {
      time : $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(
        platformEvent.data.payload.CreatedDate, 'HH:mm'),
      message : platformEvent.data.payload.Message__c
    };
    // Save notification in history
    var notifications = component.get('v.notifications');
    notifications.push(newNotification);
    component.set('v.notifications', notifications);
    // Display notification in a toast if not muted
    if (!component.get('v.isMuted'))
      helper.displayToast(component, 'info', newNotification.message);
  },
  displayToast : function(component, type, message) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get('e.force:showToast');
    toastEvent.setParams({
      type: type,
      message: message
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
  }    
})
```

Comment: Note: I currently get an error in the helper, precisely in the part: 

`var replayExtension = new cometdReplayExtension ();`

informing you that the cometdReplayExtension is not set. however I checked and javascript was loaded correctly!

Comment: If you're getting an error message, it's generally best to include that as part of your question (instead of in a comment) and to include the entire error **verbatim**.  You can [edit] your question to make this change (for the future, there is also an "edit" link that appears just under the tags for your question).